# How do I play these chords on a piano?

Tags: guitar, piano, digital-piano, electric-bass-guitar

[image: Piano Notes From Guitar Tabs]

These are Guitar Tabs. I wish for them to be converted to Piano notes. Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's no question here. The chords are already given in standard notation corresponding to the tabs.

Comment: Maybe they don’t know that guitar is transposed by an octave or can’t read standard notation.

Comment: @ojs - even so, this site is not a transcription service!

Comment: @Tim Not to mention that it says "piano" right above the notated part.

Comment: See this instructional video. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gEI7uYOCQXo

Comment: Another thing to note: the guitar is tuned down a half step: D#-A#-C#-F#-A#-D#.

Comment: @BobBroadley - rather strange tuning! Maybe Eb, Bb, Gb, Db, Ab, Eb? (or D#, A#, F#, C#, G#, D#?)

Answer (score 1):

The tabulature and standard sheet music notation in the the picture show the exact same chords. To play them on a piano, you find the corresponding keys on keyboard and press them. Music for guitar is written one octave above where it is played, so the notes on piano are played one octave lower than written.

Comment: Right, besides there is some mismatch in tuning. See e.g. bar 2, the highest note. It says (2) in the TAB on the E-string, which is F#. However, the staff above says „F# resolved = F“ …

Comment: @MS-SPO I didn't go through the whole tab, but to me it looks like the guitar is tuned down by a semitone.

Comment: Right, saw that and it‘ puzzling.

Comment: @MS-SPO it's a very common tuning in rock and metal. Some reasons for it or D standard are heavier sound, transposing down to make life easier for vocalist, easier string bending, making the same keys comfortable for guitar and horns, etc.

Comment: Yes. For a reason this info is missing on the lead sheet. For the given song it could have been tuned for further simplification (0).

Comment: @MS-SPO your comment is difficult to understand, almost like it's missing some words. Anyway, the lead sheet is missing a lot of things like song title, author and top half of the words "piano intro". There probably was a mention of tuning that was cut out for the question.